# String being split by single quotes automatically

Tags: python

I have a long string I am trying to use json.loads() on and cannot do so because from my understanding json only accepts double quotes and because of the length of this string, it is automatically being broken up to fit on new lines with single quotes.  Is there anyway to prevent this?

Example below in python 2.7

```
string = "a long string' \
         'still going"

json.loads(string)

Invalid control character fails at char #
```

I know it works if it is all double quotes or single quotes, but json.loads(string) isn't recognizing it when I use single quotes.

EDIT:

the string with single quotes is coming in from a socket, I don't have control over that.  They are taking a single quoted string and putting double quotes on the ends so that it is in line the the json.loads method.  However the single quotes that broke up the long string remain and are causing the issue

This is also not all the data for the json, just a single value of one.

Comment: Why are you trying to call `json.loads` on that data? It doesn't contain valid JSON. You could do something like this, though: `a = json.loads('"A string"')`

Answer (score 0):

Juste replace your simple quote with a `+` :

```
string = "a long string"+ \
     "still going"

json.loads(string)
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want the first line as `key` and the second as `value`.
I assume there are only two lines with `'` deliminator as the separator.

**Code:**

```
import json

string = "a long string' \
         'still going"

print json.dumps( dict([string.splitlines()[0].split('\'          \'')]) )
```

**Output:**

```
>> {"a long string": "still going"}
```

Answer (score 0):

First off all, strings in JSON is **only** `"your string"`. If you use single quotes instead double quotes in JSON it makes JSON invalid.

Btw, your string should look like

```
string = "\"My awesome string" \
    "it ends right there\""
```

or

```
string = '"My awesome string' \
    'it ends right there"'
```

or

```
string = (
    '"My awesome string'
    'it ends right there"'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured it out.  The single quotes splitting my string to new lines didn't matter because I surrounded it by double quotes after receiving it.  It turns out when I was receiving it it was adding a \n to the finishing } json bracket.  I have no idea why this \n is there, but I removed it with a simple .replace("\n", "")

just to clarify the string coming in was

```
string = 'string'
```

to put it in the json i did

```
'{"json key :", "'+string+'"}'
```